# Why isn't this linked list adding new nodes?

Tags: go, linked-list

I want to make a singly linked list and insert each data into the head. I wrote the following code, but I don't know why it gives me the wrong result.

```
type ListNode struct {
    val  interface{}
    Next *ListNode
}

func New(n int) *ListNode {
    node := &ListNode{val: n}
    return node
}

func (head *ListNode) Print() {
    for head != nil {
        fmt.Println(head.val)
        head = head.Next
    }
}

func (head *ListNode) AddToFirst(n int) {
    newHead := &ListNode{val: n}
    newHead.Next = head
    head = newHead
}
```

This is my test data

```
node := New(4)
node.AddToFirst(5)
node.AddToFirst(8)
node.AddToFirst(10)
node.Print()
```

When my input is

> 4, 5, 8, 10

I want the output

> 10, 8, 5, 4

I hope you can help me explain why this is the case. I don't understand why?
I use pointers to Add values, and I don't use reference types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first define a Node struct type, then define a ListNode struct type...
Something like :

```
type Node struct {
   val int
   next *Node
}

type ListNode struct {
   head *Node
}
```

then, your AddToFirst is obvious :

```
func (list *ListNode) AddToFirst(n int) {
   list.head = &Node{val: n, next: list.head}
}
```

Beware of your Print() function : it should not modify the list, only iterate on it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `AddToHead`, in particular:

```
 head = newHead
```

The `head` variable is the pointer pointing to the head. When you assign `head` to the `newHead`, the `node` variable you used to call `AddToHead` does not change, the copy of `node` variable (which is `head`) changes. So you never really update the head.

One way you can fix this is by returning the new head:

```
func (head *ListNode) AddToFirst(n int) *ListNode {
    newHead := &ListNode{val: n}
    newHead.Next = head
    return newHead
}
```

And use it:

```
node := New(4)
node=node.AddToFirst(5)
node=node.AddToFirst(8)
node=node.AddToFirst(10)
node.Print()
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same before, it works, I just don't understand why I don't work with the pointer without returning any value.

Comment: "The head variable is the pointer pointing to the head. When you assign head to the newHead, the node variable you used to call AddToHead does not change, the copy of node variable (which is head) changes. So you never really update the head."

I don't know why?

Comment: Let's say `node` is a variable at address 1, pointing to the head at address 2. When you call `node.AddToFirst`, a copy of `node` is sent as the receiver, say at address 3. This is also pointing to address 2. When you assign `head=newHead`, you're setting the variable at address 3, not the one at address 1.

Answer (score 0):

I Changed my code.

```
func AddToHead(head **ListNode, n int) {
    newHead := &ListNode{val: n}
    newHead.Next = *head
    *head = newHead
}
```

Call method

```
    node := New(4)
    AddToHead(&node, 5)
    AddToHead(&node, 8)
    AddToHead(&node, 10)
```